# Is there any way to use WhatsApp on an older iPad (iOS 12)? If not, why not?

Tags: ios, ipad, whatsapp.app

I have WhatsApp installed on my iPhone. I regularly use WhatsApp Web to check and post to WhatsApp from my laptop.  I would like to also use WhatsApp on my iPad.  Unfortunately my iPad is an older model that cannot be updated past iOS 12.  I've tried using WhatsApp Web in Safari on the iPad but it does not seem to work.  I haven't found any documentation that explicitly states that WhatsApp Web *cannot* work on an older iPad; the closest I've found is [this page](https://www.redmondpie.com/install-whatsapp-web-on-ipad-thanks-to-ios-13-and-ipados-13/), which says

> With the release of iOS 13 and iPadOS 13.1 Apple is making one huge change to Safari that is going to make it much more useful for many people...  That change is the move to make Safari behave like a desktop web browser, ensuring websites provide the full experience rather than a cut down mobile version. One byproduct of that is the fact you can now use the WhatsApp Web interface on an iPad, too.

This suggests that the problem is that Safari in iOS 12 only will load the mobile version of a webpage, and seems to leave open the possibility that perhaps if I used a different browser on my old iPad I might be able to make this work.  But alas, so far I have been unsuccessful; I tried Firefox, which looked at first like it was loading the WhatsApp Web interface and then hung.

Is there any way to make this work, and if not, why not? (If it's genuinely impossible then it's clearly not just a Safari limitation, or else I could work around it by using a different browser.)

Comment: I forget. Is there a request desktop version control in mobile safari on your version for iPadOS?

Comment: @bmike There is, but it doesn't seem to solve the problem -- the WhatsApp loading screen shows up and then nothing ever shows up.  (This is the same behavior that occurs in Firefox.)

Comment: Bummer - using their support may not be pleasant or informative… maybe someone here will have an answer sooner instead of later